# How can I prevent the python.el that ships with Emacs 23 from EVER loading?

Tags: emacs, python

I use python-mode.el instead of python.el for python work, and all of my customizations depend on it. However, periodically for some reason the python.el that ships with Emacs23 will magically get loaded and suddenly all of my configuration just goes out the window.

How can I prevent this?  Right now, I have this code in my .emacs:

```
(if featurep 'python)
    (unload-feature 'python))
```

That seems to reduce the instances of this happening, but sometimes I'll open a python file -- in the same session! -- and it'll get the python.el python-mode instead of the python-mode.el version.  And yet, the next buffer over still has the old mode.

This is quickly driving me bananas!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It all depends on how you've set up your .emacs.

By default, the function `'python-mode` is associated with the package `python.el`.  You need to change that with the following:

```
(autoload 'python-mode "python-mode" "Python Mode." t)
```

That assumes the `python-mode` package is already on your `load-path`.  You'll also need to be sure that the above happens in your .emacs before anything causes the `python.el` to be loaded.

These other two lines are probably not needed, but don't hurt:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.py\\'" . python-mode))
(add-to-list 'interpreter-mode-alist '("python" . python-mode))
```

If that doesn't work, then we'll need more information.

---

Another alternative is to override the functions that are auto-loaded from `python.el`, which as of Emacs 23.1 are the following:

```
(defun run-python (&rest args) nil)
(defun python-mode (&rest args) nil)
(defun jython-mode (&rest args) nil)
(defun python-shell (&rest args) nil)
```

If you define those in your .emacs, then the autoloads that Emacs sets up will have no effect.  You'll have to load `python-mode.el` manually (since the autoload for `python-mode` doesn't need to be run (because you defined that function)).  Load the `python-mode.el` with:

```
(load "/path/to/python-mode.el")
```

Answer (score 3):

Should it happen again, it signals a bug in `python-mode.el` too. Python-mode.el – that's my endeavour – should be designed in a way, `python.el` does not disturb, even if loaded.

In case, please make an [entry at the bug-tracker](http://launchpad.net/python-mode).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply remove python.el (and perhaps the .elc?  Is that still the extension for the compiled file)

Comment: The problem there is that the .el.gz file is part of the core Emacs distribution, over in non-user-space.

Answer (score 1):

One nice thing is to inspect the file loading depedency via the
`load-history` variable.  Search for the cons `(require . python)` in it. This cons will be associated to a loaded file. This
might help in order to understand the load depedencies and modify the
load sequence of the different python modes.

To make sure you never load python.el and python.elc, get rid of it in emacs's installation files. And add this to your init file:

`(autoload 'python-mode "python-mode")`

But if you cannot do that because some other package depends on it, you can try to put the following in you init file. It loads python-mode.el after python.el and overrides its definitions:

`(require 'python)
(require 'python-mode)`

I have experienced the same problem. Even though I had a proper
`(require 'python-mode)` form in my init.el and no load
requirement to python.el.  In my case, python.el kept on being loaded
after python-mode.el which overrode my settings.  It was due to
semantic/wisent/python.el which tries to load python.el.

Answer (score 0):

the following link may also be relevant..

http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.cedet/4935

i use python-mode and despite the above advised code featuring in my .emacs, i still had to do things like..

```
M-x py-pdbtrack-toggle-stack-tracking  ; followed by..
M-x python-pdbtrack-toggle-stack-tracking
```

..to actually turn off a feature.

the culprit was the wisent-python.el python.el dependency which caused the re-loading of some common variable defs. i commented the (require 'python nil t) as i already manually define the include path that it (the code requiring this file) sets up anyway.